# Can someone who systematically downvotes my posts be banned from doing so?

Tags: discussion, support

**Original post in April 2016**

For the past several weeks/months, I notice that someone has/have regularly downvoted:

- my most recent posts
- my old posts which were most recently upvoted by others.

The quality of the downvoted posts varies, and I think the motivation of the behaviour is personal.

I have been living with it. But is it normal?

---

**Updates in Oct 2016**

A new pattern about the behavior is that around the time of 23:30 once in a few days, the downvoter fumbled in my account for some posts which got upvoted recently to downvote. See my screenshots below.

The behavior happened **much less frequently recently** than it did when I posted this in April, probably because I have been less active on the main site. But it is personal targeting, persistent and without good reasons. If I begin active again, I believe that behavior will also happen much more frequently, see my reputation records in April, March, February, and January.

If possible, can the downvoter be identified and discouraged from continuing the behavior?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Comment: I closed this merely because you're asking how normal something is which isn't really an answerable thing. Maybe ask it like this: "Are others seeing a systematic downvote of their posts"?

Comment: I appreciate your inquisitive nature but the ratio of questions to answers, I think, is something that "some" may construe as lack of effort on your part, or that you're merely trying to get rep by asking questions which are obvious. I'm not judging, only stating what I'm observing.

Comment: @slm: I appreciate your thought about others' construes.  I can imagine somehow how those people's minds behave in those ways. To me, I don't think I am qualified enough to educate others and judge if they are right or wrong, and it is better for me not to mislead others.

Answer (score 7):

This is tough question and I am not here for too long to understand everything about this site, but even though I managed to *encounter some of your questions* and act upon them (answering, finding solution, up-voting or down-voting, closing or re-opening). Some of **your questions** are really **interesting** and I appreciate the imagination and the ideas you have to put various pieces together and formulate questions which (usually) makes sense.

This is *Question and **Answer** site*. By visiting your profile, everyone can see that you asked **589 questions** and **answered 2** (your own) questions (by today). It evokes one question. Did you ever learn something from them during these years? Quoting your profile information

> *Just a slow learner.*

does not help that. Being slow does not mean that you do not learn anything at all. I understand you give your part to the site by the questions, by the votes and accepting the answers. But some people might not see it this way.

Did you consider:

- Checking Review queues?
- Answering questions of some other lerners? The questions are coming back over and over again. I believe you would be able to answer some of them pretty easily.
- Checking [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)? I see you miss **Informed** badge.
- If you come up with some non-trivial question, did you considered offering a bounty on it?

It might **show your profile in brighter colors** and motivate other people to behave more friendly (not that in current state it would excuse their behavior). Don't consider this as an offense against your person. It is my point of view, but other people might see it the same way or even worse light and act upon that (down-vote is the easiest and anonymous way).

<sup>Disclaimer: I am **not** the one who down-votes you if it is just for the sake of you. It it is sick behavior.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know that person and have never pissed him/her off, then it's not normal at all. Otherwise, in my experience, **some people tend to do that when they're seriously mad at you**. Doing this **for some weeks or even months seems quite unusual** though, especially if you don't know why.

**Can you see/guess if it is a bot?** That would be the only reasonable explanation how somebody would do this over such a long time.

Comment: Thanks. I don't personally attack others. All I can see is that it is not mature.

Comment: @Tim comments like these can already cause this behavior, you may not even realize what upsets some people. I've never seen a case like this going for more than some days though.

Comment: I don't comment on others personally, except that they did things consistently disturbing.